# Is there a way to respond and continue working with NodeJs in Azure Functions?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

So in Azure Functions C# there is a component that will respond to the the invoker of the function with a custom status (i.e `202`) and then the function keeps running. In NodeJS however to respond to the invoker you need to use `context.res` or `context.done()` and both of those terminate the run and then any pending async/await calls throw an error or the `context.res` part is skipped entirely. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Durable Functions:

[image]

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const client = df.getClient(context);
    const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);

    context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);

    return client.createCheckStatusResponse(context.bindingData.req, instanceId);
};
```

in the previous sample, it will process req.params.functionName in the background and will offer an endpoint to query the status.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode

Comment: Is this the only option?

Comment: you can implement it by yourself too (using queues)